# std::async analogue for specified thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, asynchronous, future

I need to work with several objects, where each operation may take a lot of time.

The processing could not be placed in a GUI (main) thread, where I start it.

I need to make all the communications with some objects [on asynchronous operations](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/368026/architecture-for-working-with-several-devices), **something similar** to [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) with [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) or [`QtConcurrent::run()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html) in my main framework ([Qt 5](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/)), with [`QFuture`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuture.html#details), etc., but it doesn't provide thread selection. I need to work with a selected object (objects == devices) in only one additional thread always,

because:

1. I need to make a universal solution and don't want to make each class thread-safe
2. For example, **even** if make a thread-safe container for QSerialPort, [Serial port in Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html#details) cannot be accessed in more than one thread:

> Note: The serial port is always opened with exclusive access (that is, no other process or thread can access an already opened serial port).

3. Usually a communication with a device consists of transmit a command and receive an answer. I want to **process each Answer exactly in the place where Request was sent** and don't want to use event-driven-only logic.

So, my question.

How can the function be implemented?

```
MyFuture<T> fut = myAsyncStart(func, &specificLiveThread);
```

It is necessary that one live thread can be passed many times.

Comment: standard library has futures since c++11, find some standard library review book and check how to use them.

Comment: There are other questions that need to be answered before we can work with this. For example, do you have any method of making a specific thread do the work? A future class? What do you have, what do you need to implement?

Comment: @AndrewKashpur that is what my question is about. [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) can not do that

Comment: well, do you realy need to do it async ? cant you have one thread with loop, in which you iterate via device interfaces and read data from devices if any without blocking, and then iterate via commands queue and send pending commands to devices ?

Comment: @N00byEdge I described what I need to implement - function for "async" start other functions. Also I've attached link to my related questions. As I wrote, I don't have future class

Comment: @AndrewKashpur may be my global problem could be solved with thread, loop and Tasks, but what if I want to create exactly `myAsyncStart`. Also, anyway, I need to understand how own Future could be implemented

Comment: @AndrewKashpur myAsyncStart may be a useful wrspper for thread, loop and tasks

Comment: well, If i'd required to implement future/asynStart, future would be struct with value and state, and asyncStart would create and return future object which would be modified when functor passed to asyncStart would be completed. It would add task to thread, the task would consist of functor and modification of future object. Its all should also by syncronised, of course. Thats what i can come with with my limited knowledge of subject. I'm pretty sure thre are better ways to do this, which I'm am unaware of.

Comment: @AndrewKashpur as I inderstand, there is no ready-to-use solutions to store any function and its parameters in c++

Comment: look into std::function, variadic templates and tuples

Comment: So what's wrong with `QtConcurrent::run()`? BTW I am pretty sure that refusing to go for an event driven solution is the wrong approach here. But feel free to make a mistake so you can learn from it :) Also, you can go for a customizable template solution that will save you the boilerplate by generating it.

Comment: @dtech `QtConcurrent::run()` uses random thread from a pool. But although it contains all the necessary code to store functions and parameters (private code), at the moment I have no idea to pull it out from the huge private class hierarchy.

Comment: Your problem seems to be related to resources which are tied to one specific thread, you mention QSerialPort. Can you please explain how "func" is supposed to get access to such resources? Which types are the parameters and result of myFunc supposed to be?

Comment: @FourtyTwo "func" is the same that we can pass into `std::async` or `QtConcurrent::run` i.e. any function or method, which can return a value, and any parameters. As for thread resources, all it will "live"  in one thread always, threrefore it will not be a problem

Comment: maybe the [active object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_object) can help? Also see an example of implementation [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/prefer-using-active-objects-instead-of-n/225700095)

Comment: @MikevanDyke yes, it is the helpful link. But in this case I have to write a trivial wrapper class to every object method, which of course is not so easy as invoke one universal function in one line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to follow the Active Object approach here is an example using templates:

The WorkPackage and it's interface are just for storing functions of different return type in a vector (see later in the `ActiveObject::async` member function):

```
class IWorkPackage {
    public:
        virtual void execute() = 0;

        virtual ~IWorkPackage() {

        }
};

template <typename R>
class WorkPackage : public IWorkPackage{
    private:
        std::packaged_task<R()> task;
    public:
        WorkPackage(std::packaged_task<R()> t) : task(std::move(t)) {

        }

        void execute() final {
            task();
        }

        std::future<R> get_future() {
            return task.get_future();
        }
};
```

Here's the ActiveObject class which expects your devices as a template. Furthermore it has a vector to store the method requests of the device and a thread to execute those methods one after another. Finally the async function is used to request a method call from the device:

```
template <typename Device>
class ActiveObject {
    private:
        Device servant;
        std::thread worker;
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IWorkPackage>> work_queue;
        std::atomic<bool> done;
        std::mutex queue_mutex;
        std::condition_variable cv;
        void worker_thread() {
            while(done.load() == false) {
                std::unique_ptr<IWorkPackage> wp;
                {
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck {queue_mutex};

                    cv.wait(lck, [this] {return !work_queue.empty() || done.load() == true;});
                    if(done.load() == true) continue;

                    wp = std::move(work_queue.back());
                    work_queue.pop_back();
                }

                if(wp) wp->execute();
            }
        }
    public:

        ActiveObject(): done(false) {
            worker = std::thread {&ActiveObject::worker_thread, this};
        }

        ~ActiveObject() {
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck{queue_mutex};
                done.store(true);
            }
            cv.notify_one();
            worker.join();
        }

        template<typename R, typename ...Args, typename ...Params>
        std::future<R> async(R (Device::*function)(Params...), Args... args) {
            std::unique_ptr<WorkPackage<R>> wp {new WorkPackage<R> {std::packaged_task<R()> { std::bind(function, &servant, args...) }}};
            std::future<R> fut = wp->get_future();
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck{queue_mutex};
                work_queue.push_back(std::move(wp));
            }
            cv.notify_one();

            return fut;
        }

        // In case you want to call some functions directly on the device
        Device* operator->() {
            return &servant;
        }

};
```

You can use it as follows:

```
ActiveObject<QSerialPort> ao_serial_port;
// direct call:
ao_serial_port->setReadBufferSize(size);
//async call:
std::future<void> buf_future = ao_serial_port.async(&QSerialPort::setReadBufferSize, size);

std::future<Parity> parity_future = ao_serial_port.async(&QSerialPort::parity);

// Maybe do some other work here

buf_future.get(); // wait until calculations are ready
Parity p = parity_future.get(); // blocks if result not ready yet, i.e. if method has not finished execution yet
```

---

EDIT to answer the question in the comments: The AO is mainly a concurrency pattern for multiple reader/writer. As always, its use depends on the situation. And so this pattern is commonly used in distributed systems/network applications, for example when multiple clients request a service from a server. The clients benefit from the AO pattern as they are not blocked, when waiting for the server to answer.
One reason why this pattern is not used so often in fields other then network apps **might** be the thread overhead. When creating a thread for every active object results in a lot of threads and thus thread contention if the number of CPUs is low and many active objects are used at once.
I can only guess why people think it is a strange issue: As you already found out it does require some additional programming. Maybe that's the reason but I'm not sure.
But I think the pattern is also very useful for other reasons and uses. As for your example, where the main thread (and also other background threads) require a service from singletons, for example some devices or hardware interfaces, which are only availabale in a low number, slow in their computations and require concurrent access, without being blocked waiting for a result.

Comment: Could you add a little note about why this pattern and solution is not widely used and many people think it is a strange issue?

Comment: Your worker thread is doing pointless work in the loop. It is checking the queue state and what's worse, it is pointlessly locking and releasing the mutex. A better alternative to active waiting in `worker_thread` is to use `std::condition_variable` to notify worker thread about new item in the queue, not to check its state endlessly.

Comment: @VladimirBershov I tried to answer your question (Edit at the bottom of the answer)

Comment: @Rames You're right, I added the condition variable

Comment: I just add that of course one can easily reorganize the code for use *only one additional thread for multiple objects*.

Comment: This is great, many thanks! Could you please add an example how to get the result when using a function with non-void return type in the async call?

Comment: @FourtyTwo I edited my answer and added the example of the `QSerialPort::parity`-function which returns the `Parity` checking mode. The result is obtained via the future returned by the `async`-function (also for void types, if you want to check if the method request has already finished the execution)

Answer (score 7):

Let me answer without referencing to Qt library since I don't know its threading API.

In C++11 standard library there is no straightforward way to reuse created thread. Thread executes single function and can be only joined or detachted. However, you can implement it with producer-consumer pattern. The consumer thread needs to execute tasks (represented as `std::function` objects for instance) which are placed in queue by producer thread. So if I am correct you need a single threaded thread pool.

I can recommend my C++14 implementation of thread pools as tasks queues. It isn't commonly used (yet!) but it is covered with unit tests and checked with thread sanitizer multiple times. The documentation is sparse but feel free to ask anything in github issues!

**Library repository: https://github.com/Ravirael/concurrentpp**

And your use case:

```
#include <task_queues.hpp>

int main() {
    // The single threaded task queue object - creates one additional thread.
    concurrent::n_threaded_fifo_task_queue queue(1);

    // Add tasks to queue, task is executed in created thread.
    std::future<int> future_result = queue.push_with_result([] { return 4; });

    // Blocks until task is completed.
    int result = future_result.get();

    // Executes task on the same thread as before.
    std::future<int> second_future_result = queue.push_with_result([] { return 4; });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's Qt. It's signal-slot mechanism is thread-aware. On your secondary (non-GUI) thread, create a `QObject`-derived class with an `execute` slot. Signals connected to this slot will marshal the event to that thread.

Note that this `QObject` can't be a child of a GUI object, since children need to live in their parents thread, and this object explicitly does not live in the GUI thread.

You can handle the result using existing `std::promise` logic, just like `std::future` does.

Comment: This is what I did so far, but the method is uncomfortable and requires a lot of boilerplate code